# C# Call Base method with another THIS

Tags: c#

I have the following method in the base class:

```
public class Base  
{
protected string Make(string param)
        {
            return this.ClientID + "_" + configParam;
        }
}
```

And i have another class

```
public class Class2 : Base  
{

}
```

And

```
public class Class3 : Base  
{
 //HERE i would like to call Make but with the THIS as Class2, not the current - Class3.
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer. NO

Comment: Thanks Nikosi for the answer.

Comment: With the structure of the classes that you have, `Class3` is a _sibling_ of `Class2`. Those classes are unrelated to each other. Thinking biologically, you inherit your genetics from your parents, not your brother and sister.

Comment: Inject Class2 instancje into Class3 and then make a call  on class2Instance.Make(). This could work.

Comment: Well you can always instantiate an instance of Class2 inside Class3 and call methods on it. But you really need to rethink your structure here, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you change the base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want only subclasses of `Base` to invoke `Make`, even if it's not their own `Make`, you can add a `protected` invoker method (I call it `InvokeSiblingMake`):

```
public class Base
{
    private string ClientID;
    protected string Make(string param)
    {
        return this.ClientID + "_" + param;
    }

    protected void InvokeSiblingMake(Base other)
    {
        other.Make("hello world");
    }
}

public class Class2 : Base  
{

}

public class Class3 : Base
{
    //HERE i would like to call Make but with the THIS as Class2, not the current - Class3.
    public void Test(Class2 other)
    {
        InvokeSiblingMake(other);
    }
}
```

Comment: @krillgar Thinking biologically, its like running to your parents and asking them to make your brother do the dishes :P

Answer (score 0):

With the structure of the classes that you have `Class3` is a sibling of `Class2`. You inherit from your parents, not your brother and sister. This means **there is no way** to cleanly call a method on `Class2` from within `Class3` through means of `base`.

There are ways around that by giving a `Class2` member variable to `Class3`, however at that point you're not using inheritance. In that approach, `Class2` could inherit from `System.Object`, `System.DateTime` or any other class you may create yourself. Then you're acting **on the object set as the property**, and ***not*** **through inheritance**.